# cmpfunc in bsearch() in c

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am learning the use of function pointer from a programming book. There i've found the use of bsearch() and qsort(). The two functions has a parameter of function pointer cmpfunc.

In qsort() cmpfunc is needed to compare two elements.

I don't understand why there is a need for cmpfunc in bsearch() and how it works.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can only assume what you mean, but usually you pass a comparison function to a sorting function to allow the user to choose their own sorting scheme, i.e. allowing the user to sort elements in ascending or descending order, or sort them after their value mod 5, or really anything you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Array-Search-Function.html) documentation, the `bsearch` comparator function, similar to the one used the `qsort` function, is needed to evaluate the desired candidate to the elements in the array. This is neede to terminate the search if the desired element is contained or discarding half of the search space in every iteration; the role is the same as in the `qsort` function.

Answer (score 1):

In `bsearch` the comparison function `cmpfunc` is called to decide whether the element being examined actually matches the key, and if it does not, whether the key will be earlier or later in the list.

Comment: Thanks @Ross Presser.